# SELECT from different tables, and get one result [mysql] [union] or [join]

Tags: mysql, join, union

Guys are You able to help me please to build a proper mysql select with joins of these below selects?

My selects separately looks like that:

```
SELECT budget as budget from projects where id =96

SELECT sum(value) as expenses from expenses where project_id =96 

SELECT sum(estimated_hours * t2.man_hour) as estimated from project_has_tasks t1 left join 
users t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id where project_id =96

SELECT sum(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME (time_spent),'%k.%i' )
* t2.man_hour) as time_spent_cost FROM project_has_tasks t1
left join users t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id where t1.project_id ='96'
```

They works ok but I wanna to achieve one result like:

```
| budget | expenses  | estimated | time_spent_cost |
____________________________________________________
| 298833 |   24234   |  4434333  |   343434        |
```

Anyway I've just built a common select but it doesn't work properly
(incorrect sums...)

```
SELECT t1.project_id, t3.budget, 
IFNULL(sum(t4.value),0) as additional_costs, 
IFNULL(sum(estimated_hours)* t2.man_hour ,0) 
as estimated_hours_costs, 
IFNULL(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME 
(sum(t1.time_spent)),'%k.%i' )* t2.man_hour,0) 
as time_spent_cost, NOW() 
FROM project_has_tasks t1 left join 
users t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id left join 
projects t3 on t1.project_id = t3.id 
left join expenses t4 
on t1.project_id = t4.project_id 
WHERE t1.project_id ='96' group by t1.project_id
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the sums are too high, I assume both expenses and users to return more than one row and sums are calculated on all rows, hence if there are three users, then estimated will be thrice the value you want. Assuming projects to only return one row, this may work better:

```
    SELECT t1.project_id, t3.budget, 
           (SELECT sum(IFNULL(t4.value,0))
            FROM expenses t4 
            WHERE t1.project_id = t4.project_id) as additional_costs, 
           sum(IFNULL(t1.estimated_hours* t2.man_hour,0)) as estimated_hours_costs, 
           sum(IFNULL(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME (t1.time_spent),'%k.%i' )* t2.man_hour,0)) as time_spent_cost, 
           NOW() 
    FROM project_has_tasks t1 
    left join users        t2 on t1.user_id    = t2.id
    left join projects     t3 on t1.project_id = t3.id 
    WHERE t1.project_id ='96'
    group by t1.project_id
```

Comment: Almost :) Budget, and additional_cost are ok, but estimated_hours, and time_spent are not correct. Too small values.

Comment: If I'll group by user_id I've got:
https://preview.ibb.co/cG74FU/Schowek_1.jpg

I need sum also  estimated_hours, and time_spent to get 1740, and 1320

Comment: Can I join this? 

SELECT sum(estimated_hours * t2.man_hour) as estimated from project_has_tasks t1 left join users t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id group by project_id

SELECT sum(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME (time_spent),'%k.%i' )* t2.man_hour) as time_spent_cost FROM project_has_tasks t1
left join users t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id group by project_id

Comment: SUM ought to have been outside the IFNULL, of course. Don't know if this have had any impact regarding the result, but I've modified my answer (and added t1. where I'd forgotten it). Other than this, I don't see any differences compared to your separate queries...

Comment: Thanks a lot master.